# Loading values from a properties file in java based configuration using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration

How can I read the values of a properties file while using javabased configuration of a Spring 3.2 MVC application? 
My configuration class extends WebMvcConfigurationAdapter...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo.bara" , excludeFilters = { @Filter( Configuration.class ) } )
@PropertySource( {"classpath:abc.properties", "classpath:persistence.properties" } )
public class MokaWebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 
    @Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ] {
            new ClassPathResource( "persistence.properties" ),
            new ClassPathResource( "abc.properties" )
    };
    pspc.setLocations( resources );
    pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
    return pspc;
  }
    ...
}
```

When trying to access this resource whith

```
@Value('${persistence.db.driverClass}') private String driverClassName;
```

${persistence.db.driverClass} is not recognized.

What do I have to do to read values from properties files in a @Configuration class? 
I think I cannot use an Environment instance in this place, can I?

Answer (score 3):

Do it the right way...and it works!
You have to use double quotes rather than single quotes, of course:

```
@Value("${persistence.db.driverClass}") private String driverClassName;
```

rather than

```
@Value('${persistence.db.driverClass}') private String driverClassName;
```